# Save contact thumbnail on file

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

I would like save a profile picture in a file on localstorage.

With this code retrieval IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType but I don't understand how to save it on disk.

```
var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
contactPicker.CommitButtonText = "Select";

var contact = await contactPicker.PickSingleContactAsync();

using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await contact.GetThumbnailAsync())
{
    //Save stream on LocalFolder
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType` works like any other stream, this should do the trick:

```
using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await contact.GetThumbnailAsync())
{
     using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("path", FileMode.CreateNew))
     {
          stream.CopyTo(fs);
     }
}
```